# iframe stops reloading and shows the error

Tags: iframe

I have a few iframes which load the content from the same domain (by refreshing every minute). They normally work fine but when the tab with the page is hidden and after some time I click back to activate the tab with the page (which contains the iframes) I get the following error grey screen inside the iframes:
A network change was detected.

[image]

When I reload the page – the iframes resume the refreshing every minute.
I wonder how to force the iframes to refresh all the time?
I uploaded the screenshot
Thanks a lot!)

Comment: I am using this line to refresh the pages inside the iframes:<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"/>

Comment: or should I instead use the javascript to reload the page: <body onload="javascript:setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); },5000);">